# A and B toss a coin 10 times, what is the probability that A wins?

Tags: probability

A and B toss a fair coin 10 times. In each toss, if its a head A's score gets incremented by 1, if its a tail B's score gets incremented by 1.

After 10 tosses, the person with the greatest score wins the game.

What is the probability that A wins?

And if B alone gets an extra toss. What is the probability that A wins?

According to me, 
The cases where A can win are

(Score of A, Score of B)

(6,4)

(7,3)

(8,2)

(9,1)

(10,0)

These are A's winning cases. Now I am confused on how to proceed.

One method I can think of is that in each of these 5 cases the probability them happening is (1/2)^10. So the probability of A winning is 5*(1/2)^10

But I think I am not taking into consideration the various occurrences of the winning tosses from the total tosses.

So should the probability of A winning be like

(10C6 + 10C7 + 10C8 + 10C9 + 10C10 ) / 2^10

Which is the number of possible outcomes for A divided by the total number of outcomes. Where 10C6 is the number of ways of selecting 6 from 10 items

Comment: Yes, what you have in the end is correct!  ... Now, how would you handle the extra 1 toss for B alone?

Comment: can you find probability of a draw?  It is then half the chances that it is not a draw - by symmetry.   This is like the card one that just came up, same technique

Comment: on the extra toss - the extra toss is only any good to B if it is a draw after 10, either he won, drew or lost 6-4 or worse - so then actually B's chances are increased by half the draws, making 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be obvious, from symmetry, that, in the first case, where the coin is flipped 10 times, that A and B have the same probability of winning.  But if there are 5 heads and 5 tails, neither wins.  The probability of that is $(1/2)^{10}\begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}= \frac{252}{1024}= \frac{63}{251}$ so the probability that there is no tie, that either A or B wins is $1- \frac{63}{251}= \frac{181}{251}$.  Since A and B are equally likely to win, the probability A wins is half that, $\frac{181}{502}$.

I don't understand what you mean by "if B alone gets an extra toss."  In the original question, it didn't matter who flipped the coin- just whether the flip resulted in "heads" or "tails".  Are you just saying that B wins if "heads" and "tails" come up an equal number of times?  In that case, the probability that A wins is the [b]same[/b].  The only difference is that, now, the probability that B wins is the probability that A does NOT win.

Comment: the extra toss isn't very clear, it must mean B gets a final chance to call toss 11, but A doesn't

Comment: Suppose the "11th toss" means we add 1 to B's score with probability $p$ and add nothing to either score with probability $1-p.$ Then the probability A wins is still unchanged. The only thing affected by the choice of $p$ is the proportion in which the "A does not win" event is divided between the "B wins" event and the "nobody wins" event. The only way for the 11th toss to change the probability of A winning is if there is a non-zero probability that the 11th toss will break a tie in A's favor, that is, if A has a chance to gain score from that toss.

Answer (score 1):

It should indeed be (10C6 + 10C7 + 10C8 + 10C9 + 10C10 ) / 2^10

Here is why:

There is only one way for (10,0) to be the outcome:

HHHHHHHHHH ... which happens with a probability of $(\frac{1}{2})^{10}$

But there are 10 ways for (9,1) to be the outcome:

HHHHHHHHHT

HHHHHHHHTH

...

THHHHHHHHH

Each of these happens with a probability of $(\frac{1}{2})^{10}$, and you have 10 of them, since the 1 T can happen in one of 10 places. So, probability of getting 9 H and 1 T is $10*(\frac{1}{2})^{10}$

For (8,2) to be the outcome, you need 2T's among 8H's ... which can be done in ${10}\choose{2}$ ways .. and thus indeed you the general formula that you indicated at the end.